# Memory leak in Chromium browser on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, chromium, debian-buster

I'm running chromium-browser, "Version 88.0.4324.187 (Officiel version) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32-bit)", on a Raspberry Pi:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I use it for displaying a Grafana dashboard, but after 15-20 minutes, I get this screen (yes, it's in Danish):

[image]

Examining memory use, it looks like a memory leak:

[image]

Starting chromium from command line, I get

```
$ chromium-browser
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[1028:1028:0706/100238.539582:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(150)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[981:1166:0706/100239.765246:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[981:1166:0706/100239.766394:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[981:1166:0706/100239.770222:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
```

...and when the error occurs:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1:0xa6c9000]  2424902 ms: Scavenge 208.8 (235.1) -> 207.0 (235.1) MB, 10.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.428, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure 
[1:0xa6c9000]  2424964 ms: Scavenge 208.8 (235.1) -> 207.3 (235.4) MB, 14.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.428, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure 
[1:0xa6c9000]  2428824 ms: Mark-sweep 210.8 (237.1) -> 209.4 (237.9) MB, 3347.9 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.323, current mu = 0.168) allocation failure GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->
```

Is this a known bug? Can I do anything about it?

Comment: I too am experiencing a memory leak with the version of chromium. Running a periodic task in javascript (via jquery) which updates a div results in memory being gobbled up according to the rate of the task. This is a new problem for us, so I suspect it is a chromium bug in a recent release. No solutions yet, but working on it.

Comment: Better post this question on the official Chromium developer Google group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev